# Importing LDIF file users.ldif error

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap, ldif, opends

[image]

Error which I got is:
Configuring Directory Server Done.

Importing LDIF file users.ldif

unable to read data from users.ldif file

error reading users.ldif file

users.ldif file exists in directory c:\openDS

Hence the server is configured without ldif file

How to resolve?

Comment: Please show your code/configuration or whatever may be needed to analyze your problem.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.